# xlsxwriter: write_array_formula not getting calculated when in another sheet

Tags: xlsxwriter

My goal is to use write_array_formula and refer to a range of cells in another sheet. I'm trying this code:

```
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')

sheet1 = workbook.add_worksheet('Sheet1')
sheet2 = workbook.add_worksheet('Sheet2')

sheet1.write('A1', 'Foo')
sheet1.write('A2', 'Bar')

sheet1.write_array_formula('B1:B2', '{=Sheet1!$A$1:$A$2}')
sheet2.write_array_formula('B1:B2', '{=Sheet1!$A$1:$A$2}')

workbook.close()
```

With this code I was expecting for column B of Sheet1 and Sheet2 to be identical. But it appears that the formula is not being calculated in Sheet2.

Here's what column B looks like in Sheet 1:

[image: "Foo" in row 1 and "Bar" in row 2]

And here's what column B looks like in Sheet 2:

[image: Nothing in row 1 and "0" in row 2]

Comment: This looks like a bug in XlsxWriter. I'll investigate it and post an update.

Comment: I've created a GitHub [issue](https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/issues/735) for this and pushed a fix to the XlsxWriter master branch. I'll push the fix out in a new release in the next day or two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that this was the result of a [bug](https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/issues/735) in XlsxWriter that went unnoticed for a long time.

It is fixed in XlsxWriter [version 1.3.1](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/changes.html) and later. Thanks.